# Tascam DP008EX Panning on input source not reflected in monitor

Tags: stereo, panning, tascam

I'm confused. When I pan the signal on the source, the input levels on my Tascam DP008EX make sense - when the signal is panned left the input level display for channel A is high and when panned right, the one for channel B is high. However, this is not reflected in what I hear in my headphones, where the balance remains constant.

Furthermore, with the input signal panned fully left, the pan knob for channel B does nothing to the monitor signal, while the one for channel A gives a loud signal in both ears when turned left, and a quiet signal in the right ear when turned right.

Can someone explain what is going on please?

Comment: Haven't used the said hardware so I can't provide some useful answer, but have you checked that the monitoring happens in stereo and not by sending the A channel to both ears?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a technical support request, best addressed to the manufacturer.